# VBA turning a list into a 5 column table

Tags: excel, vba, list, loops

I have a list (vertical) that i want to arrange it as table.
Let say i have around 23 list. and i want to arrange in 5 columns and skipping one row each.
example from this list style;

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
s
t
u
v
w
```

to this format;

```
 1| a | b | c | d | e |
 2|   |   |   |   |   |
 3| f | g | h | i | j |
 4|   |   |   |   |   |
 5| k | l | m | n | o |
 6|   |   |   |   |   |
 7| p | q | r | s | t |
 8|   |   |   |   |   |
 9| u | v | w |   |   |
10|   |   |   |   |   |
```

I had a thought of using looping and using "step", but im unsure if it will work

Comment: An outer loop with a step of 2 to increase row number, with an inner loop of 5 times to increase column number and fetch & insert the next list item. This is my natural thoughts. Try coding with the help of Office help documentation, and use step into debugging.

Comment: I'm confused about "vertical" and "'a' to 'w'", which would infer a horizontal list. Is the original data vertical (up and down) or horizontal (left to right)? And you have "around 23", so does that mean that this changes? I would assume even if it does that you wouldn't ever have more than 25 since you are asking for a 5x9 (with row spacing). If you could please [edit] your question with more detail it would certainly help.

Comment: okay i have edit it. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working with small data, a couple of loops shouldn't be an issue whatsoever. Even with small data, I'd still at least recommend that you work with arrays instead of reading/writing each value to the worksheet one at a time.

You could create two array variables, `OldArr()` and `NewArr()`. You will place the existing column of data into `OldArr()` and clear the data since you will be overwriting it with your 5x5.

Then with `NewArr()`, you simply loop through the rows/columns representation of the worksheet and reorganize the data as required. Then write the entire array to the worksheet in one pass.

Something like this should work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColumnDataToBox()

    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim OldArr() As Variant
    With ws.Range("A1:A25")
        OldArr = .Value
        .Clear
    End With
    
    Dim NewArr(1 To 9, 1 To 5) As Variant, c As Long, r As Long, i As Long
    For r = 1 To 9 Step 2
        For c = 1 To 5
            i = i + 1
            NewArr(r, c) = OldArr(i, 1)
        Next c
    Next r

    ws.Range("A1:E9").Value = NewArr

End Sub
```

This would assume the data size is never greater than 25 rows (since you were asking for a 5x5) and therefor this code is not dynamic.

[image]

Comment: hey davis. so far i find your answer is easy to understand. however, my mistake for not mention earlier, but how bout if i were to copy the list and paste into a table that is in another sheet. i am stuck here. i tried activate the sheet3. the loop is fine. and i think array is fine too. but when i run, the table is empty. as if nothing happens

Comment: Not exactly sure if I understand what you’re asking, but the very last line above the `End Sub` replace `ws.` with `Sheet3.`. Instead of using a variable you can just use the worksheet’s [Codename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.codename). This will place the data into sheet3 while still copying from sheet1.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
Cells.Clear
For i = 1 To 23 ' make data
Cells(i, 1) = Chr(96 + i)
Next i
For i = 1 To 23 ' transform data
Cells(((i - 1) \ 5) * 2 + 1, (i - 1) Mod 5 + 1) = Cells(i, 1)
If i > 1 Then Cells(i, 1).Clear
Next i
```

It uses a formula to calculate the new position of a cell, so no intermediate array is needed.

[image: column2rows]

Comment: Hi JMP. Im having a little hard time to understand your method. the command Chr(96+i) is new to me. may i know what is for? i tried googling it but still cant understand

Comment: `Chr` returns the character associated with the ASCII code supplied as a parameter, so Chr(97)="a", Chr(98)="b", and so on. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/chr-function. That section of my code recreates your initial column of data, which I then rearrange into the table layout.

Answer (score 0):

### Get Columns From Column

- The 1st Sub shows how to use the 2nd, the main Sub (`getColumnsFromColumn`).
- The 3rd Sub is being called by the main Sub (also necessary).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub testGetColumnsFromColumn()
    
    ' Source
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const srcColumnID As Variant = "A" ' e.g. 1 or "A"
    Const srcFirstRow As Long = 1
    ' Target
    Const tgtName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const tgtFirstCell As String = "A1"
    Const NumberOfColumns As Long = 5
    Const EmptyRows As Long = 1
    ' Other
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define source worksheet.
    Dim src As Worksheet:  Set src = wb.Worksheets(srcName)
    
    ' Write result to array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    getColumnsFromColumn Data, src, NumberOfColumns, _
        EmptyRows, srcColumnID, srcFirstRow
    If IsEmpty(Data) Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Write array to target worksheet.
    Dim tgt As Worksheet: Set tgt = wb.Worksheets(tgtName)
    tgt.Cells.ClearContents
    tgt.Range(tgtFirstCell).Resize(UBound(Data), UBound(Data, 2)) _
       .Value = Data

    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Success"

End Sub

Sub getColumnsFromColumn(ByRef Data As Variant, _
                         Sheet As Worksheet, _
                         ByVal NumberOfColumns As Long, _
                         Optional ByVal EmptyRows As Long = 0, _
                         Optional ByVal ColumnID As Variant = 1, _
                         Optional ByVal FirstRow As Long = 1)

    Data = Empty
    
    Dim ColumnData As Variant
    getColumn ColumnData, Sheet, ColumnID, FirstRow
    If IsEmpty(ColumnData) Then Exit Sub

    Dim ub As Long: ub = UBound(ColumnData)
    Dim FullSets As Long: FullSets = Int(ub / NumberOfColumns)
    Dim NoS As Long: NoS = FullSets
    Dim Remainder As Long: Remainder = ub Mod NumberOfColumns
    If Remainder > 0 Then NoS = NoS + 1
    
    ReDim Data(1 To NoS + EmptyRows * NoS - 1, 1 To NumberOfColumns)
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, CurrentRow As Long
    GoSub writeFullSets
    If Remainder > 0 Then GoSub writeRemainder

    Exit Sub

writeFullSets:
    For i = 1 To FullSets
        CurrentRow = (EmptyRows + 1) * i - EmptyRows
        For j = 1 To NumberOfColumns
            k = k + 1
            Data(CurrentRow, j) = ColumnData(k, 1)
        Next j
    Next i
    Return

writeRemainder:
    CurrentRow = (EmptyRows + 1) * i - EmptyRows
    For j = 1 To Remainder
        k = k + 1
        Data(CurrentRow, j) = ColumnData(k, 1)
    Next j
    Return

End Sub

Sub getColumn(ByRef Data As Variant, _
              Sheet As Worksheet, _
              Optional ByVal ColumnID As Variant = 1, _
              Optional ByVal FirstRow As Long = 1)
    Data = Empty
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet.Columns(ColumnID).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If rng.Row < FirstRow Then Exit Sub
    If rng.Row > FirstRow Then
        Data = Sheet.Range(Sheet.Cells(FirstRow, ColumnID), rng).Value
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rng.Value
    End If
End Sub
```